# How can I migrate MySQL Code to PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, heroku

I deployed my laravel app on Heroku for the first time which uses the MySQL database. Though when I tried to add my credit card to enable me to use MySQL addons, I get an error saying

```
Error
Unable to verify your card. Please try later or contact your financial institution for help.
```

And I tried using different cards, and I still get the same error. So I noticed that I can use
Heroku Postgres addons without adding a credit card. And that is what I used, though I have no experience using Postgres.

When I tried accessing some pages that have to fetch data or interact with my database, I get an error like this:

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 1: ...rals" inner join "users" on "referrals"."user_id" = "users"....
^
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "referrals" inner join "users" on "referrals"."user_id" = "users"."id" where "referrals"."referral_id" = gqFApQsz055fafcab840daf39379e35001d9d426) (View: /app/resources/views/User/profile.blade.php)
```

I know the cause of the error is the change of database type. **So my main question is**, **is there a way for me to migrate the MySQL code automatically to PostgreSQL**  or is there any suggestion for me to use a free remote MySQL database and connect to my Heroku application.

Comment: Have read it: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-migration-with-postgresql

Comment: @Ehsan Ahmadi Kian   I have already done the .env setup, and everything works fine, my authentication is working, it's just some query operation that gives me an error like the above which I posted. which I think is because of MySQL & PostgreSQL having differences in some query operation. So I am asking if there is a way to resolve that differences by migrating the query or someway

Answer (score 0):

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-migration-with-postgresql?page=1&replyId=147211

> Either rename or make a copy of the existing ".env.example" to ".env"
>
> Note! The values contained in the .env file is prepared for the
> Homestead box and should work with little modification if at all.
> However, if not using the Homestead VM but a Wamp or Xamp for example,
> you will need to provide the values specific to your environment.
>
> There you will have the variable names actually used through out the
> framework. For example;

```
# Add this to change driver, the default is mysql
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql  # or sqlite

# Add this if you are not using Homestead and you know the default pgsql port has not changed.
DB_PORT=5432 

# Change the values to suit your environment if not on Homestead
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=homestead  # or mainpagedb
DB_USERNAME=homestead     # or postgres 
DB_PASSWORD=secret   # or postgres

# For the Schema you can add the following 
DB_PGSQL_SCHEMA=fes

# then edit in 'config/database.php
'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        // Notice the following has been modified
            'schema'   => env('DB_PGSQL_SCHEMA','public'),
        ],
```

> You can create new environment variables (Key=>value) pairs and then
> call them elsewhere with env('Key', 'some default if key not set')
>
> The easiest way to get started with Laravel is to use the Homestead
> Virtual Machine. However, using sqlite is equally as flexible to
> start. You can later switch to a different provider. For sqlite, just
> create an empty 'database/database.sqlite' file in the folder
> indicated.